# Assigning return value to variable in Ruby in Learn Ruby the Hard Way, exercise 21

Tags: ruby, return-value, variable-assignment, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

In Zed Shaw's Learn Ruby the Hard Way, exercise 21:

```
def add(a, b)
  puts "ADDING #{a} + #{b}"
  a + b
end

age = add(30, 5)  
puts "Age: #{age}"
```

This prints Age: 35.

I tried doing this with the previous exercise (ex20):

```
def print_all(f)
    puts f.read()
end

current_file = File.open(input_file)

sausage = print_all(current_file)

puts "Sausage: #{sausage}"
```

But when I run it, #{sausage} does not print, even after I move the file pointer back to 0:

```
def print_all(f)
    puts f.read()
end

def rewind(f)
  f.seek(0, IO::SEEK_SET)
end

current_file = File.open(input_file)

sausage = print_all(current_file)

rewind(current_file)

puts "Sausage: #{sausage}"
```

I assigned the return value from method add(a, b) to age, why can't I do the same with print_all(current_file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_all(f)
    puts f.read()
end
```

The return value of `print_all` is the return value of `puts f.read()`, which is the return value of `puts`, not the return value of `f.read()`. `puts` always returns `nil`. Therefore, `print_all` always returns `nil`.

Perhaps you intended:

```
def print_all(f)
    f.read()
end
```

Or if you need to print it in your function/method:

```
def print_all(f)
    foo = f.read()
    puts foo
    foo
end
```

Comment: Is it right to say that the 'return value' of 
    def print_all(f)
        f.read()
    end
Is the action of 'reading' the input_file?

Comment: @user2835005, the return value isn't the "action" of reading, but it is the "result" of reading the input file.